# Issue with Num Pad

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, numpad

I have a problem with my <kbd>Num. Lock</kbd> key on my Toshiba Satellite C650. In fact, when I start up my computer the <kbd>Num. Lock.</kbd> button works fine, I can use it to activate the num pad and I even can type my password using the num pad but after authentication the num pad is automatically disabled and I can't activate it anymore, <kbd>Num. Lock.</kbd> seems to be useless once I get authenticated. I tried to *change the Value of the Keybord Registry Key* and uncheck `Turn on mouse keys` but this didn't solve the problem. I'm working on Windows 7 x64. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** num pad buttons work fine but not as numbers i.e: when I press <kbd>4</kbd> the cursor moves to the left. The problem is that I can't turn on the <kbd>Num. Lock</kbd>

Comment: Maybe try MS's fix once you're loggedin http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BSJDtmXIpzMJ:support.microsoft.com/kb/154529+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a

Comment: @JanDoggen that's what I have tried manually

Comment: Go to Control "Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use". In this, under the "Control the mouse with the keyboard" section, make sure that "Turn on Mouse Keys" is unchecked

Comment: It would probably help to know what kind of keyboard you have. Does the keyboard have a FN key? Is this perhaps a laptop?

Comment: @rags it's unchecked.

Comment: @druciferre : yep it's a laptop (TOSHIBA Satellite C650) and it does have a FN key

Comment: Is this your keyboard http://tinyurl.com/bp37khc ? When you press the NumLock key does the status light change?

Comment: @druciferre yes that's my keyboard and that's exactly the problem, the light status doesn't change when I press the num lock button. It only can be changed before I type my password.

Comment: Does this happen when you boot in Safe mode ?

Comment: Have you tried toggling the mouse keys option? Does this happen for all user accounts on the computer (temporarily create one if necessary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Win7 built-in "**On Screen Keyboard**" to test if <kbd>NumLock</kbd> behaves well.

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Enter <kbd>osk</kbd>
3. In bottom right corner, click "Option" and checked the Number Panel
   boxes
4. Press <kbd>NumLock</kbd>

Comment: It's the only answer that helped me. But does this mean that the num lock button (of the real keyboard :p) doesn't work??

Comment: It need to be tested. If NumLock is an individual physical button, 1) Use "AutoHotKey", 2) enter .ahk script #InstallKeybdHook and 3) View>Key History to see if NumLock works or not.
If it shows NumLock, then I suspect that some softwares may override the key.
And sometimes clear dusts of the laptop may help.

Comment: it doesn't show NumLock. I guess it's broken. Anyway, thanks for your help :), at least now I know where it comes from and how to activate it. It was hard for me to use a keyboard without Number Pad.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue definitely sounds software related. If you're certain you've disabled Mouse Keys from the Ease of Access Center, then it seems like some other software is providing Mouse Key functionality. Perhaps something from Toshiba. I would suggest looking through your startup items for anything that sounds like *Ease of Access* or *Accessibility* and disabling it. You can use `msconfig` to do this, but I would suggest using [`Autoruns` from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) since it is more thorough.

If you do **File** > **Save** from `Autoruns` and send me the file, then I can look through it and tell you if there anything that might be causing it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, how can I send it to you, can you give me you email adress

Answer (score 0):

.Hi Hedi!

You can try to check BIOS settings too, BIOS setting for num lock should not be conflicting with the registry details. Just click the correct key on your Toshiba to load the BIOS then view Boot Device Menu, choose System Setup, look for POST Behavior then check the Num Lock Key Option. Make sure its Num Lock is Turn On, Save and Exit the SetUp page before rebooting the computer.

Have a great day!

~kryte

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once and it turned out to be an `ease of access` problem.

I'd recomend you go to:

`Ease of Access Center` under `Make the keyboard easier to use` and uncheck all the checkboxes you find there.

I don't know exactly what option I unchecked, but it's OK if you uncheck it all.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Turned my computer on this morning and the number lock wasn't working. I plugged in a different usb keyboard and windows downloaded driver for that keyboard. That keyboard worked with no issues so I tried the old keyboard and it seemed to fix that issue as well.

PS my virus scan had also remove 2 possible threats the night before...